# Accidentally pushed temporary branch to origin, want to discard it

Tags: git, github

I had created a local throw-away branch `temp`, and accidentally called

```
git push --all origin
```

which added it to my github repo.

I then deleted the `temp` branch locally and did another

```
git push --all origin
```

but the branch still exists in github, though no longer associated with the master branch. How can I tell my remote repo to git rid of `temp` branch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following command will solve your issue

`git push origin :temp`

This command has to be understood as *"replace the remote branch `temp`with nothing"*

alternatively, you can also perform the following one, which is a shortcut to the one above.

`git push --delete origin temp`

For more information, you can refer to the **[documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)**.